# ¿Como asignar un valor a Trackbar dinamicamente en Windows forms?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo la necesidad de asignar un valor a varios controles "trackbar" en Windows forms, por lo que quisiera hacerlo con un bucle "for" la idea que tengo es tan simple como este ejemplo:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 50; i++)
{
 trackbar(i).Value = i;
 i++;
}
```

Esto esta mal, no se cual es la sintaxis o la forma correcta de hacerlo, alguien de ustedes si? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Queres asignar el valor a todos los trackbar dentro de un formulario? o sólo algunos? depende de algun tipo de condición?

Comment: Solo a algunos, tengo 50 trackbar, trackbar1,trackbar2,trackbar3, etc.. los tengo con el nombre por default y quiero aprovechar eso para recorrerlos con el indice "i" del bucle for, ej: ( trackbar{i},trackbar{i},trackbar{i}, etc..)

Comment: Bien, pero basado en que condición decidís si modificas, si recorres índices al azar modificarías todos, de que condición depende si se modifica o no? deja un ejemplo de eso..

Comment: Problema: Los controles en windows form no tienen todos el mismo nombre, entonces no se puede hacer eso como se hacia en vb6. Para lo que vos queres, hay dos opciones: agregar los controles en tiempo de ejecucion a un vector, recorrer ese vector y poner los valores o recorrer los child del form, buscar los controles que queres por nombre y cambiar el dato que queres.

Comment: igual hacer i++ dentro de un for, esta muy mal...

Comment: @gbianchi entiendo y gracias por la observación de i++ dentro de un for, no me había dado cuenta que es redundante, tu comentario al igual que el de Juan Salvador Portugal fue de mucha ayuda, gracias a ambos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacer lo que buscas, podes usar la propiedad `Control` de tipo [ControlCollection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection?view=netframework-4.7.2) del `Panel` o `Form` padre de tus `TrackBar`

Lo que haremos, será iterar los controles del formulario y así buscar los que sean de tipo `TrackBar`, por ejemplo

```
//Por cada control c en los controles del Form
foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
{
    //Chequeo que c sea de tipo TrackBar
    if(c is TrackBar)
    {
        //Lo casteo a la clase correspondiente
        TrackBar t = (TrackBar)c;
        //Chequeo lo necesario previo a modificar
        if(condicionParaModificar)
        {      
            //Modifico el Value del TrackBar               
            t.Value = 15;
        }
    }
}
```

La misma solución puede simplificarse un poco usando `Linq` y [Enumerable.OfType](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
foreach(TrackBar t in this.Controls.OfType<TrackBar>())
{    
        if(condicionParaModificar)
        {
            t.Value = 15;
        }    
}
```

---

La otra opción, sería la de ir agregando los `TrackBar` a un vector o `List<T>` a medida que vas generandolos en tiempo de ejecución, y luego, recorrer el vector como mencionas en la pregunta

```
//Definis la lista o vector
IList<TrackBar> TrackBars = new List<TrackBar>();
//Agregas los TrackBar de tu interes..
TrackBars.Add(trackBar1);
TrackBars.Add(trackBar2);
```

Luego simplemente recorres con un `foreach`

```
foreach(TrackBar t in TrackBars)
{
    t.Value = ...
}
```

o un `for` si es lo que necesitas

```
for(int i = 0; i<TrackBars.Count;i++)
{
    TrackBars[i].Value = ...
}
```

---

Teniendo en cuenta lo que plantea @gbianchi en el comentario, dejo una pequeña solución recursiva que seguramente no es la óptima pero se puede tomar como base

```
public void GetAllTrackBars<T>(T t, ref IList<TrackBar> Lista)
    where T : Panel
{
    if (Lista == null) Lista = new List<TrackBar>();
    foreach (var ctrl in t.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(Panel)) || ctrl is Panel)
           GetAllTrackBars<T>((T)ctrl, ref Lista);
    }

    foreach (TrackBar tr in t.Controls.OfType<TrackBar>())
    {
       tr.Value = ...;
    }
}
```

De esta manera bastaría con llamar la función pasándole una lista, y se ejecutaría dentro de todos los elementos `Panel` y derivados de `Panel`

```
IList<TrackBar> Lista = new List<TrackBar>();
GetAllTrackBars(panel1, ref Lista);
```

---

Una implementación un poco más genérica del último caso (tomando un segundo objeto genérico derivado de `Control`)  y de esta manera usar un delegado para definir la acción a ejecutar

```
public void GetAllTrackBars<T,Element>(T t, ref IList<Element> Lista, Action<Element> Accion)
    where T : Panel where Element : Control
    {
        if (Lista == null) Lista = new List<Element>();
        foreach (var ctrl in t.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(Panel)) || ctrl is Panel)
            GetAllTrackBars((T)ctrl, ref Lista, Accion);
        }

        foreach (Element tr in t.Controls.OfType<Element>())
        {
            Accion(tr);
        }
}
```

y lo llamaría así

```
IList<TrackBar> Lista = new List<TrackBar>();
GetAllTrackBars(panel2, ref Lista, (t) => { t.Value = ...; });
```

Comment: El problema de la primera parte, es que si el trackbar esta dentro de un frame que esta dentro de un frame que esta dentro de otro control, no lo va a encontrar.. no es simplemente iterar sobre controls... o me estoy olvidando de algo...

Comment: @gbianchi no lo pensé de esa manera, asumí que todos los controles estaban dentro del mismo panel, caso contrario supongo q sera una solución recursiva?

Comment: Probablemente.. o dependiendo la complejidad de la recursion, ir por el segundo metodo.